# How I can modify my script to randomly pick the consecutive elements of different length?

Tags: python, random

I have a data frame consists of 148 rows and 1500 columns. I require to random pick 2, 6, 12 and 24 points from each column. My script perfectly picking the random points, however, I am facing difficulty to modify my script for to pick adjacent points of 2, 6, 12 and 24 length (without connecting the 1st and last observation]

For example, if A=[2, 9, 7, 6, 0]
the random picking for 2 length should be like
(2, 9), (9, 7), (6, 0), (9, 2), (7, 9), 6, 7), (0, 6),
.. But (2, 0) or (0, 2) should not be included in random test.

Here is my script

```
df=data # My data set consists of 148 columns and 1500 rows 

for i in range(1):
    hr_ev = df.iloc[:,i] # select particular column 
    N = 1000 # lengt of data
    C =4 # number of columns
    rand_hr = np.zeros(shape = (1000,4)) # empty array
    for u,j in zip([2, 6, 12, 24],range(C)): # intervals of random picking 
        for i in range(N):
            x=np.random.choice(hr_ev, size=u, replace=True) # random picking 
            c=np.sum(x) # sum of randomly picked observations 
            rand_hr[i,j] = c 
    df_hr = pd.DataFrame(rand_hr) 
print(df_hr)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your `ev_95` variable ? It is not defined in the code you provided

Comment: Ev_95 is same as hr_ev, I have corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```py
df = data # My data set consists of 148 columns and 1500 rows 

for i in range(1):

    hr_ev = df.iloc[:, i] # select particular column 
    N = 1000 # length of data
    C = 4 # number of columns
    rand_hr = np.zeros(shape=(1000, 4)) # empty array

    for u, j in zip([2, 6, 12, 24], range(C)): # intervals of random picking 

        for i in range(N):
            start_index = np.random.randint(low=0, high=(len(ev_95) - u)) # random picking
            x = hr_ev.values[start_index:start_index + u]

            if np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5) >= 0.5:
                x = x[::-1] # Randomly reverse data with probability 0.5

            c = np.sum(x) # sum of randomly picked observations 
            rand_hr[i, j] = c 

    df_hr = pd.DataFrame(rand_hr) 

print(df_hr)
```